# Set woocommerce primary image to be the height of 4 x gallery images

Tags: css, woocommerce

I am trying to create a Woocommerce layout where the gallery is displayed on the left side of the main image. I have done this, but I'm struggling to set the height of the primary image to be the same as the height of 4 of the gallery images to the side.

With the CSS I've used, the primary image is set to 80% of the width of the container and the gallery is set to 20% of this width. But this is cropping the primary image on the right hand side as the height is still set to the same height it was before. If the primary image was set to 80% of it's current height (so the height of 4 of the gallery pics next to it) then it would not be cropped.

I would like the gallery to also be set to the same height, but if there are more than 4 images in the gallery then I would like to get a scrollbar next to it (so overflow-y:scroll;)

Do I make sense?

You can see what I've done here: http://kg.gammawebsolutions.co.za/product/planche/

The CSS I used to get the gallery on the left is this:

```
.et_pb_wc_images .flex-viewport {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
  
}
.flex-control-nav.flex-control-thumbs {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0!important;
}
.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 100%!important;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: your image is 900px in height and u set width to 100% so image will be even taller bcs its trying to fill it. I am with WQHD monitor and your image is 918x1376 if you catch my drift.

Comment: I have realised that the problem only seems to exist in Firefox. Looks fine in other browsers.